# Android : Square and square root sign

Tags: android, square-root

I am creating an app where I need to show square root signs along with numbers. 
E.g.

```
  /¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
\/  (v^2) / T
```

I am also looking to show square of a number. 
Can anyone help in displaying such text. This text comes from a database and can change.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `√` **[U+221A - Unicode Square Root](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm)**.

For squared, use  `²` **[U+00B2 - Unicode Superscript Two](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)**.

However, I expect that you will have to draw these advanced symbols using standard graphics primitives - text will likely be too limiting for such task.